# GAE python: why is searching through the datastore so slow? What is a good search query algorithms?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using google app engine datastore and have around 1500 blog posts in the datastore.

Using ndb

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

So I'm using

```
words = self.request.get("q")
search_words = words.split()

query = libs.blogs_cache() # returns a list of blogs memcache
search_results = [blog for blog in query for word in search_words 
            if word.lower() in blog.title.lower()]
```

This is an example I use for the time being. But unfortunately, this is extremely slow (takes around 6 seconds) because you have to go thru every single data to find the results. If you use multiple words, it will multiply the number of search.

So my question is. What are some ways to speed up the search and google app engine? Any examples and directions to it would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for this type of search , you should use google app engine search api.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

just feed the data in the search documents and you can then query through them

Comment: I thought about using that too. But you can't customize your own search. And the price looks a bit scary for minimum 100 queries.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't customize your own search"? Consider to setup something like elasticsearch and use it. Datastore is not for a full text search, but for simple words queries you can speed it up by splitting all the words and storing them in repeated property.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. By customize, I thought it'd be easier to just use python to make the query and add more functionalities to it later.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: there is lot of functionality available in search api too like logical operators, counts etc. you should go through documentation , you will find this feature very useful. if you want to stick with simple python checking, then you will have to compromise for speed and this will not be scalable as well.

Comment: tipsywacky  The last thing you want to do is look at all the results in the datastore to find something. Look up "indexes".

Answer (score 1):

If there are not too many words in `search_words`, you can make an [`IN`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) query on the `title`:

```
search_words = [word.lower() for word in words.split()]
search_results = BlogPost.query(BlogPost.title.IN(search_words)).fetch()
```

Notice that this matches the title exactly which might not be what you want and if you need to query for lowercase blog titles, you probably also have to make a [`ComputerProperty`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think @omair_77's answer is likely best, but an alternative to consider, if the blog posts and the search lists are small enough, is a **computed property**:

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    words = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: content.lower().split())
```

Now, `BlogPost.words.IN(words.lower().split())` will give you the desired semantics -- all blogs containing at least one of the words in space-separated string `words`, case-insensitive.

If you need to ignore punctuation you'll likely want regular expressions instead (`re.findall(r'\w+', whatever.lower()`) instead of the simple `split` calls, but the general ideas in GAE terms are the same: computed properties can be used in queries, and that `IN` operator locates entities with at least one "hit" -- and it does so rapidly, using indices on the "back-end side" of things.

Comment: Feeding a tuple/list to `ComputedProperty` returns `NotImplementedError: Property ... does not support <type 'tuple'> types.` this solution is unfeasible, sadly enough